# filtering deep nested objects array using lodash not working correctly

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have product structure as shown below:

```
   product = {  
  "name":"MyXam",
  "layers":[  
    {  
      "countries":[  
        {  
          "countryId":"1",
          "countryName":"ABC"
        },
        {  
          "countryId":"2",
          "countryName":"XYZ"
        },
        {  
          "countryId":"3",
          "countryName":"PQR"
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "countries":[  
        {  
          "countryId":"5",
          "countryName":"LMN"
        },
        {  
          "countryId":"3",
          "countryName":"PQR"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And selected countries:

```
selCountries =    [  
  {  
    "countryId":"1"
  },
  {  
    "countryId":"3"
  }
]
```

Now I want to filter the `product` in such a way that it should contain `countries` only  that are in `selCountries`.

The final product should be:

```
{  
  "name":"MyXam",
  "layers":[  
    {  
      "countries":[  
        {  
          "countryId":"1",
          "countryName":"ABC"
        },
        {  
          "countryId":"3",
          "countryName":"PQR"
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "countries":[  
        {  
          "countryId":"3",
          "countryName":"PQR"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following using lodash but is not working:

```
_.filter(product.layers, _.flow(
      _.property('countries'),
      _.partialRight(_.some, selCountries)
  ));
```

As the `product` comes dynamically in my application. In some cases there is a possibility that some of the `layers` may have not `countries`. So the solution should handle this case also and should not break with undefined error.

Can any on help me, where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer's similar to 31piy's in that I extract out the ids from `selCountries` first, and then rebuild the object with the filtered results. It also checks whether there are countries in the layers array as per your recent comment.

```js
product = {"name":"MyXam","layers":[{"countries":[{"countryId":"1","countryName":"ABC"},{"countryId":"2","countryName":"XYZ"},{"countryId":"3","countryName":"PQR"}]},{"countries":[{"countryId":"5","countryName":"LMN"},{"countryId":"3","countryName":"PQR"}]}]}
const selCountries=[{"countryId":"1"},{"countryId":"3"}];

if (product.layers.length) {
  const selCountriesArr = selCountries.map(el => el.countryId);
  const newLayers = product.layers.map(obj => {
    const countries = obj.countries.filter(el => selCountriesArr.includes(el.countryId));
    return { countries };
  });
  const filteredProduct = { ...product, layers: newLayers };
  console.log(filteredProduct);
}
```

Comment: Andy, it should work across all layers not at index 0, as in your solution product.layers[0]. Can we make it generic?

Comment: Well, I can only base my answer on the details in your question. Perhaps you could update your question with this new information so I can understand.

Answer (score 2):

You should not need lodash for that. Just `filter` based on ID. If for all layers, map/forEach on the layers and filter the countries.

```js
const product = {  
  "name":"MyXam",
  "layers":[  
    {  
      "countries":[  
        {  
          "countryId":"1",
          "countryName":"ABC"
        },
        {  
          "countryId":"2",
          "countryName":"XYZ"
        },
        {  
          "countryId":"3",
          "countryName":"PQR"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const selCountries = [  
  {  
    "countryId":"1"
  },
  {  
    "countryId":"3"
  }
];

const indices = selCountries.map(e => e.countryId); // Just IDs plz.
product.layers.forEach(layer => {
   if (layer.countries == null)
       return;

   layer.countries = layer.countries.filter(e => 
       indices.some(i => i == e.countryId)
   );
});
console.log(product);
```

Comment: As in my application the product comes dynamically and in some cases the layer may not have countries also, in that case the it is throwing error saying undefined of filter. Is there any simple way to handle this in your solution

Comment: @MadasuK: Probably add a null check before filtering. Changed the code to forEach (modifies layers in-place!). But don't you want to wait for the product to load?

Comment: Even then some times from server side response missing that countries property.

Comment: I would probably just set the property to an empty array if there are no results.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary array with the IDs of countries selected, and then filter the countries based on it. Note that it modifies the original object in-place.

```js
let product = {
  "name": "MyXam",
  "layers": [{
    "countries": [{
        "countryId": "1",
        "countryName": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "countryId": "2",
        "countryName": "XYZ"
      },
      {
        "countryId": "3",
        "countryName": "PQR"
      }
    ]
  }]
};

let selCountries = [{
    "countryId": "1"
  },
  {
    "countryId": "3"
  }
];

// Extract the IDs
let selCountryIds = _.map(selCountries, 'countryId');

// Filter the countries based on IDs
product.layers[0].countries = _.filter(product.layers[0].countries, country => {
  return _.includes(selCountryIds, country.countryId);
});

console.log(product);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It should work for all layers not just at index 0 as given in the solution product.layers[0]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `lodash`, you can make use of `Array.map` and `Array.filter` to iterate through the array and filter the `product` as per the `selected countries.`

```js
var product = {  
  "name":"MyXam",
  "layers":[  
    {  
      "countries":[  
        {  
          "countryId":"1",
          "countryName":"ABC"
        },
        {  
          "countryId":"2",
          "countryName":"XYZ"
        },
        {  
          "countryId":"3",
          "countryName":"PQR"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


var selCountries =    [  
  {  
    "countryId":"1"
  },
  {  
    "countryId":"3"
  }
];

product.layers = product.layers.map(function (layer) {
  return layer.countries.filter(function (country) {
    return selCountries.some(function(selCountry) {
      return selCountry.countryId === country.countryId;
    });
  });
});

console.log(product);
```